# GraphQL union and conflicting types

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I've got an issue on my project and I can't find any solution on the internet. Here is the situation.

- I've an Union (`DataResult`) of 2 types (`Teaser` & `Program`)
- I've a `Zone` type with a `data` field (an array `DataResult`)
- `Teaser` & `Program` have the same `title` field with a different type (`String` vs `String!`)

Here is parts from `Zone`, `Teaser` and `Program` schemas:

```
type Program {
    title: String
}

type Teaser {
    title: String!
}

union DataResult = Teaser | Program

type Zone {
    (...)
    data: [DataResult!]
}
```

When I tried to query zone data as described in the query part below, I've got an error from GraphQL.

```
zones {
    ...zoneFieldsWithoutData
    data {
        ... on Program {
            ...programFields
        }
        ... on Teaser {
            ...teaserFields
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: GraphQL error: Fields \"title\" conflict because they return conflicting types String and String!. Use different aliases on the fields to fetch both if this was intentional
```

I can't use an alias because the specs needs the same attribute name for all "DataResult" entities. What can I do ?

Moreover, even if I set the same Type for `title`, I've a lot of warning about "missing fields" in the console....

PS: I use Vanilla Apollo as GraphQL client (on the server side)

Comment: Can maybe help... https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1065

Comment: I believe this is related to https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/53 and https://github.com/facebook/graphql/pull/120 - as long as concrete type is known, fields with the same name shouldn't collide.

Comment: Looking at it from a plain JS objects point, you are expecting something like `{ data { title: 'Title 1', title: 'Title 2' }}` which doesn't make a lot of sense since you might not differentiate between what title belongs to Program or Teaser and that's why it insists on using aliases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170603/graphql-using-same-field-names-in-different-types-within-union and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379796/how-to-query-same-field-with-different-types-in-an-union

Answer (score 5):

I know that you cannot use an alias, but for everyone else who can (including me):

The simple answer taken from [github](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1361#issuecomment-393489320) is to use field aliases:

```
zones {
    ... on Program {
        programTitle: title
    }
    ... on Teaser {
        teaserTitle: title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an [interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) solved this problem for me, including the "missing field" - errors (although this means the fields have to be of the same type I think).

Something along the lines of

```
interface DataResult {
    title: String!
}

type Program implements DataResult {
    // Not sure if this can be empty?
}

type Teaser implements DataResult {
    // Not sure if this can be empty?
}

type Zone {
    (...)
    data: [DataResult!]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented according to the specification:
See 3.a at: http://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#SameResponseShape()

See https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1361#issuecomment-393489320 for more details.